# Python multidimensional x_train scikit-learn

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

So I am trying to classify title to description using SVMs. My data looks like the following:

```
x_train = [
    #hashingvectorizer
    #string
    #hashingvectorizer
]
y_train = #string

classifier = svm.SVC()
classifier.fit(x_train,y_train)
```

this gives me the following error: `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence`

I know this is because the values in my `x_train` list are not the same size or something along that regard, but I don't know another way to do this. How could I reorganize my data or do something so that I can have this style of multidimensional data?

### Example of data:

data in `x_train` before vectorized looks like the following:

```
[[
    "this is a description that could be in any form, but not too large",
    "title",
    "tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4,tag5,...,tagn"],
 [...],
 [...]
]
```

data in `y_train` looks like the following:

```
[[
    "classified_group1",
    "classified_group2",
     #...
    "classified_groupn"],
 [...],
 [...]
]
```

### Full traceback

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-e3356a0f62f8> in <module>()
----> 1 classifier.fit(X,y)

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.pyc in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    140                              "by not using the ``sparse`` parameter")
    141 
--> 142         X = atleast2d_or_csr(X, dtype=np.float64, order='C')
    143 
    144         if self.impl in ['c_svc', 'nu_svc']:

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.pyc in atleast2d_or_csr(X, dtype, order, copy)
    114     """
    115     return _atleast2d_or_sparse(X, dtype, order, copy, sparse.csr_matrix,
--> 116                                 "tocsr")
    117 
    118 

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.pyc in _atleast2d_or_sparse(X, dtype, order, copy, sparse_class, convmethod)
     94         _assert_all_finite(X.data)
     95     else:
---> 96         X = array2d(X, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
     97         _assert_all_finite(X)
     98     return X

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.pyc in array2d(X, dtype, order, copy)
     78         raise TypeError('A sparse matrix was passed, but dense data '
     79                         'is required. Use X.toarray() to convert to dense.')
---> 80     X_2d = np.asarray(np.atleast_2d(X), dtype=dtype, order=order)
     81     _assert_all_finite(X_2d)
     82     if X is X_2d and copy:

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.pyc in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    318 
    319     """
--> 320     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    321 
    322 def asanyarray(a, dtype=None, order=None):

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: can you show a little sample of `x_train` and `y_train` and give their shapes too?

Comment: @toine I have shown the exact structure of the data now. The actual data is confidential so I cannot share that

Comment: Can you reproduce the error with a working script using fake data? Do your data consist of lists of strings or lists of lists of strings? From what you are showing, they might, and this may be at the root of the problem.

Comment: @eickenberg my data set is simply strings, but I am using a vectorizer, which converts them to a matrix so that the training data can be used on them. I assume if these are different sizes that this is what is creating the error. But I need to use all 3 data fields so how can I make that work?

Comment: I saw that they are strings. It is just so much more handy to have a piece of copy+pasteable code to play around with. Maybe somebody with enough experience will spot the error as something recurrent and be able to help you out. All I can do here is possibly fix a broken example. Have you looked at `X` using a debugger? If so, what is it? (type, dtype, shape, ...)